# Why does smoke render as transparent in the OpenGL render?

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation, opengl

In the viewport, smoke looks fine:

[image: Smokey cube in the viewport]

However, when I render it with the OpenGL render:

[image: Smokey cube rendered with OpenGL]

It looks white because of the background; it's really transparent.

What causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider that a bug.

It appears that when the smoke flow object is set to Fire or Fire+Smoke it renders transparent with opengl render.

The fire simulator uses it's own material settings to preview in the 3dview - not the material settings that we configure. It would appear that this preview material works in the 3dview but not the opengl render.

Comment: [Reported](http://developer.blender.org/T37834)

Comment: For reference this is fixed in source builds after 18 Dec 2013 - will be in release 2.70